# MySQL Query eliminate duplicates but only adjacent to each other

Tags: mysql

I have the following query..

```
    SELECT Flights.flightno, 
    Flights.timestamp, 
    Flights.route
FROM Flights
WHERE Flights.adshex = '400662' 
ORDER BY Flights.timestamp DESC
```

Which returns the following screenshot.
[image: results]

However I cannot use a simple group by as for example BCS6515 will appear a lot later in the list and I only want to "condense" the rows that are the same next to each other in this list.

An example of the output (note BCS6515 twice in this list as they were not adjacent in the first query)
[image]

Which is why a GROUP BY flightno will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a good way to do so in SQL without a column to help you. At best, I'm thinking it would require a subquery that would be ugly and inefficient. You have two options that would probably end up with better performance.

One would be to code the logic yourself to prune the results. **(Added:)** This can be done with a [procedure clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-procedures.html) of a select statement, if you want to handle it on the database server side.

Another would be to either use other information in the table or add new information to the table for this purpose. Do you currently have something in your table that is a different value for each instance of a number of BCS6515 rows?

If not, and if I'm making correct assumptions about the data in your table, there will be only one flight with the same number per day, though the flight number is reused to denote a flight with the same start/end and times on other days. (e.g. the 10a.m. from NRT to DTW is the same flight number every day). If the `timestamp`s were always the same day, then you could use `DAY(timestamp)` in the `GROUP BY`. However, that doesn't allow for overnight flights. Thus, you'll probably need something such as a departure date to group by to identify all the rows as belonging to the same physical flight.

Comment: I had some similar thoughts after reading your post and have structured the data better so that this issue can't even happen in the first place!

Comment: That's definitely the better way to go ^_^

Comment: Yeah did that and much better!

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY does not work because 'timestamp' value is different for 2 BCS6515 records.

it will work only if:

```
SELECT Flights.flightno, 
    Flights.route
FROM Flights
WHERE Flights.adshex = '400662' 
GROUP BY (Flights.flightno)
```

Comment: That does not have the desired effect as it groups all of the flightno's together!  I need it so that only adjacent ones are grouped.